# Connecting PyCharm to WinSCP

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm, winscp

i am using Pycharm to write python code and all the time have to upload the code via WinSCP to the server.

Is there a way to make this process easier?

Comment: WinSCP has a CLI, so it'd be pretty easy to script the transfer.

Answer (score 3):

From pycharm,

GoTo `File` -> `Settings`

You will get a pop-up window of settings. Select the `plugins` then click on `Browse repositories` at the bottom.

Then you will get the pop-up window of `Browse repositories`, search for `Source synchronizer`. Then click on `Install` to install that plugin for `scp`, `ftp` ...

**Restart** the pycharm

Now you can make use of it to do `scp`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Remote File Systems plugin from JetBrains Marketplace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/big-data-tools-remote-file-systems.html)!

The plugin provides support for the following remote file systems:

- AWS S3 Google Cloud Storage Azure Alibaba OSS Tencent COS MinIO
  DigitalOcean Spaces Linode HDFS Yandex Object Storage SFTP

With this, I was able to integrate it into my PyCharm Professional environment, replacing WinSCP and MobaXTerm :)